# Would it be a good idea to set up a newsletter sign-up form in simple PHP?

Tags: php, html, email, newsletter

I would like to add a form that allows my site visitors to sign up for a newsletter from my site.

I started to build the form, but apparently it's not such a good idea and instead I should use prebuilt scripts by other people to do this as they would be more secure.

Would it really be all that bad to make my own and just have it query all the signups into a database? I don't want it to be all that complex, just need something simple, but I definitely don't want to jeopardize the security of people signing up.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good idea if you can make it secure. It's not rocket science, it is as difficult (in term of security) as any other task in PHP involving writing data to a DB.

Comment: Is the PHP script also going to be sending the emails, or is it only going to provide an interface for people to add their info to the database?  Are you providing opt-out functionality as part of the PHP script, or is that handled by another application/service?

Comment: It's just going to be querying their name and email into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself if you know how to write it correctly.

The reason why people use tried and tested code is because you may be black listed by email services due to large volume of emails you would be sending. Once you are black listed then it is difficult to get yourself off the black list. The tried & tested code SHOULD send the newsletters out periodically rather then mass emailing at once.

Other reasons is due to security, if you write the code incorrectly or if you are new to forms which access databases, then it may not be sensible to write your own. It is good practice to learn it though, even if in the mean time you have to use someone else's code.

Comment: Well I'm going to be sending out emails to everyone on the list at once when I do send them, but I won't be sending them out all the time, maybe 2-3 times a month. Would that still get me blacklisted? I'm not talking about an automated newsletter that compiles emails to send out, I'll be writing them myself.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well I see no reason as why you wouldn't be able to do it.
Just ensure that the forms have client side & server side validation, removing special characters from the forms etc. Make sure you MD5 hash and salt passwords into your database, make it more secure.
You must keep client information secure, but if you are just keeping a list of first names & email address, then don't be put off writing your own.

Comment: Yeah, look into sha256 or sha512 to store passwords. But what I did stop by to say was, definitely go ahead and code it yourself. Sooner or later, you will need to write PHP code that stores data in DBs, and there's only so long you can avoid it. PHP/SQL security doesn't need you to be a genius, or even smart - just thorough.

Comment: I actually have some experience with PHP/MySQL and forms from a project I'm working on now, but I'm just making it functional to start (not doing anything with securing them yet), so that's why I'm a bit nervous about this.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to verify emails addresses by a confirmation request email and an associated form. In addition if you have a larger list (more than a few hundred members), then you must code bounce handling and unsubscriptions. For a small list you can do these manually. I did build such a web application step-by-step, but if I had to start it now, than I would consider an existing mail list software more seriously. At first I also thought that I only need a small form, and the list managers I checked was indeed difficult to integrate, but in the long run it was too much effort.